Rollup configuration for single file output
I am trying to figure out the configuration for my required output.
I have a number of components, each stored within their own folder in the root folder prod. In prod I then have a file components.js that imports each of these components. Consequently, there will be multi entry points in the output.
components.js
import "./component_1/component_1.js";
import "./component_2/component_2.js";
import "./component_3/component_3.js";
etc.

The rollup process completes and it works fine, with the resulting files in the dist folder. However, about 500 files are created by the process.
Is this the way Rollup works, or is there a way to reduce the number of output files, ideally to a single file?
rollup.config.js
import { createBasicConfig } from "@open-wc/building-rollup";
import dynamicImportVars from "@rollup/plugin-dynamic-import-vars";
import merge from "deepmerge";
import multi from "@rollup/plugin-multi-entry";
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";

const baseConfig = createBasicConfig({
    developmentMode: false,
    outputDir: "dist",
    output: { inlineDynamicImports: true }
});

export default merge(baseConfig, {
    input: { include: ["prod/components.js"], entryFileName: "js_components.js" },
    plugins: [nodeResolve(), multi(), dynamicImportVars()]
});


You could try the following NPM package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-singlefile
